# Garbage collection being successful seems to depend on non-related things

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm trying to consistently force objects to be garbage collected, for purposes of writing unit-tests related to weak references.
However, `GC.Collect()`, which [I expect to force garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912797/testing-verifying-a-weakreference), does not seem to behave consistently.
Consider the following example code.

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
    var obj = new object ();
    var wRef = new WeakReference (obj);

    obj = null;
    GC.Collect ();
    Console.WriteLine (wRef.IsAlive); // Prints false.
    Console.ReadKey ();
}
```

In the code above the object seems to be collected, while in the code below this is not the case, although the code is virtually the same.

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
    var obj = new object ();
    var wRef = new WeakReference (obj);

    obj = null;
    GC.Collect ();
    bool alive = wRef.IsAlive ? true : false;
    Console.WriteLine (alive); // Prints true
    Console.ReadKey ();
}
```

Can someone explain this behavioral difference, and show how we can reliably have objects getting reclaimed in order to do some testing with weak references?

**Update**

When running the second snippet in release mode without a debugger attached (i.e. outside Visual Studio) it prints False.

Comment: I'm not sure as to why it is happening, though I *can* say, it seems to behave as expected in Release mode without a debugger attached. Otherwise the second snippet always returns true.

Comment: Make sure you run it *outside* Visual Studio. For me, with the debugger attached (i.e. VS), it returns true. Without the debugger attached it returns false.

Comment: It ought to be sufficient to run the Release config  'without debugger'.  But you should really test this with your Unit Test framework.

Comment: I know the JIT knows when a debugger is attached and will handle things differently. Not sure as to what *specifically* is causing your issue here. Seems to be something along that path, though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman In NUnit it behaves exactly the same. Needless to say, it has too many drawbacks to always have to run your unittests in release mode without a debugger.

Comment: Just go to the properties of the test Project and enable Optimization in all configurations. And accept that those tests fail while debugging them. Shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Garbage Collection should have removed object but WeakReference.IsAlive still returning true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205891/garbage-collection-should-have-removed-object-but-weakreference-isalive-still-re)